# To get Server's date and time to client machine

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 4-5 clients machines and one server. I want the server's date and time but not the clients date and time. If i need the clients date and time i could have used DateTime.Now in c# and var date= new Date() in jQuery. But I dont want this. I want the server's date and time it may be using jQuery or webservices or mvc.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will return the server time (the code is running on the server after all!)

Comment: Thanks alot for ur comment... But when we take DateTime.Now we get the date and time of the current system which we are working on.

Comment: Exactly. Since the C# code is running on your web server, it will return the current DateTime of the server.

Comment: And you cannot get the clients `DateTime` with _i could have usedDateTime.Now in c#_. A web browser has no concept of c# code

Comment: Thank you in advance. If suppose I want to get the Date and time outside my web server. How can I do that?

Comment: Date and time of what? You can either render the DateTime of the server (using `DateTime.Now` and render the value in the view which gets sent to the client, or on the client you can get the clients date using javascript ` var date= new Date()`. Not sure what your trying to do.

Comment: Sorry For confusing you. Suppose i want the date and time of google.com server?

Comment: Lijo's answer should help with that.

Comment: Yaaa.. Lijo's answer worked out for me.. Thank you soo much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string URL = "http://www.google.com";    
System.Net.HttpWebRequest rq2 = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL);
System.Net.HttpWebResponse res2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)rq2.GetResponse();
DateTime Date = DateTime.Parse(res2.Headers["Date"]);
```

Now , you can get server side date and time in your DateTime variable

Comment: Does this piece of code give me the "http://www.google.com" server's date and time?

Answer (score 2):

The server's time can be obtained only when you render the page to the server. You can set it in a javascript variable as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var serverTime = '<%=DateTime.Now%>';
    alert(serverTime);
</script>
```

This returns a string. You'll need a little more work to convert it to datetime.

If you need to get the server time without a postback, you need to call an web service to get the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the server date and time by ajax call i.e:

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "datetimereturn",
        type: "post",
        success: function (result) {
            alert("date time : " + result)
        }
    });

});
```

and on server:

```
public string datetimereturn(){
     return DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```